# VBA Macro: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with the syntax on a VBA macro. Trying to create a select from Sheet 2 list on Sheet 1, and it gives me Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub Macro1()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Select
With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="Sheet2!$A$1:$A$14"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With


End Sub
```

Please help me understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: selection is in activesheet, change to full referenced range in your with statement. Depending on case, you first need to delete validation before adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the macro more than once, you need to ensure you delete any existing validation

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Validation
        'Remove existing validation
        .Delete
        'Add new validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, _
             Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$14"
           'Note - need ^ (i.e. the equals sign to make it a formula)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End Sub
```